# How to connect to another db using stored procedures?

Tags: oracle, database-link, stored-procedures

I need to get some data from an external db and make some calculations with it in another db, is it possible to connect to an external db from a stored procedure? Thanks guys.

PS.

Im using Oracle and both databases are in the same server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use a Database Link (DBLink).

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm

http://psoug.org/reference/db_link.html

```
-- create tnsnames entry for conn_link
conn_link =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = perrito2)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orabase)
    )
  )


CREATE DATABASE LINK conn_user
USING 'conn_link';

SELECT table_name, tablespace_name FROM user_tables@conn_user;
```

@conn_user on the end of a procedure or table name will tell the pl/sql engine to query the db link specified for that info.

Comment: Embedded deep within your PSOUG link is a reference to the DRIVING_SITE hint - performance of queries across DBLINKs can vary greatly - if you KNOW where most of the data processing is going to be done, be sure to set the DRIVING_SITE to the database where the data processing will be most efficient.

Comment: 11g documentation http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/ds_admin002.htm#ADMIN12150

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can, you can read data from about any database using dg4odbc. Any odbc complient database can be connect to and Oracle database providing you can find a working odbc driver for out platform. .odbc.ini and $ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin are your configuration locations.